# Is it valid to call operator-- for an iterator when it points to std::begin()

Tags: c++, stl

Is it valid to call operator-- on an iterator that already points to the first element of the collection? Does the answer change for different collections (e.g. list vs vector vs set). E.g. see below

```
#include <algorithm>
#include <iostream>
#include <numeric>
#include <string>
#include <vector>
 
int main()
{
    std::vector<int> v {1, 2, 4, 8, 16};

    auto i=v.begin();
    auto j=i;
    --i;  // not sure what's the effect of this
    v.erase(j);
    ++i;  // also not sure if this is not std::begin() anymore, what's the effect of ++
    v.erase(i);

 
    // Print vector.
    std::for_each(v.begin(), v.end(), [](const int n) { std::cout << n << ' '; });
}
```

I suspect it's undefined behaviour but not quite sure.

Furthermore, what about removing elements from a std::list like below

```
    std::list<int> v = { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6 };
 
    for (auto it = v.begin(); it != v.end(); it++)
    {
        v.erase(it--);
    }
```

Comment: You cannot decrement an iterator to the first element of a range.

Comment: Aside: `v.clear();` does the same as your loop, as does `for(auto it = v.begin(); it != v.end;) { it = v.erase(it); }`

Comment: only `forward_list` has a "before-begin iterator", but you can't get to it by decrementing

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let's take `std::list` as an example, because essentially the same reasoning will apply to the other containers.

Looking at the [member types](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/list#Member_types) of `std::list`, we see that `std::list::iterator` is a [LegacyBidirectionalIterator](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/named_req/BidirectionalIterator). Checking the description there, we see the following precondition listed for `operator--` to be valid:

> Preconditions:
>
> - `a` is decrementable (there exists such `b` that `a == ++b`)

This is not the case for an iterator to the first element in a container, and indeed cppreference explicitly calls this out:

> The begin iterator is not decrementable and the behavior is undefined if `--container.begin()` is evaluated.

Other containers like `std::vector` use more expansive notions like [LegacyRandomAccessIterator](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/named_req/RandomAccessIterator), but there's nothing there that changes the behavior of decrementing a begin iterator.